# Pyvmomi what does this do?

Tags: python, sdk, vmware, pyvmomi

i'm currently working on the VMware SDK in python (with Pyvmomi) and I see in all sample or example this line:

```
atexit.register(Disconnect, self.si)
```

Does anyone know what does is supposed do ? I don't understand, thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a program, you may have uncaught exceptions, or something else like a socket which is kept open, this leads to undesired behaviors. To resolve this, the module [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) is there for you.

It allows you to register multiples functions / methods to call at program end.  If the object is deleted, `self.disconnect()` is called.

Comment: Thanks for u specification.